# 2 сетевые карты, реализация 2х подключений одновременно

Tags: ftp

на компьютере с виндой 2 сетевые карты. 1 на интернет, 2  подключение к рабочему серверу FTP, так же через 2 работают программы типа вкс. интернет с динамическим IP, ни какие настройки не прописаны

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В настройках сетевой карты в сторону FTP должны быть только адрес и маска. Ни шлюза, ни чего-либо ещё быть не должно. Если FTP и/или прочие нужные сервисы, достижимые через эту сетевую, находятся в другой подсети - прописать соотв. частные перманентные маршруты. Всё.